# create a raw json to nested json object - javascript

Tags: javascript, json, parsing, nested

my array that i download from the server looks like this,

```
array=[ { icon: 'm-warning',
    color: '#FDC204',
    name: 'exp1',
    team: 'c',
    user: 'alpha' },
  { icon: 'm-puzzle',
    color: '#86AF45',
    name: 'exp2',
    team: 'c',
    user: 'alpha' },
  { icon: 'm-refresh',
    color: '#77A746',
    name: 'exp3',
    team: 'c',
    user: 'alpha' },
  { icon: 'm-puzzle',
    color: '#86AF45',
    name: 'exp3',
    team: 'a',
    user: 'beta' },
  { icon: 'm-clock',
    color: '#4677A7',
    name: 'exp4',
    team: 'b',
    user: 'beta' },
  { icon: 'm-warning',
    color: '#FDC204',
    name: 'exp5',
    team: 'a',
    user: 'gamma' } ]
```

If i need to create a nested object( # of exps, belonging to respective teams, organized by user)  from the above array how would i go about it. my resulting nested object shud look like this, (notice alpha has 3 exps belonging to team c) and so on and so forth

```
[{
  id: 'gamma',
  data: [
    ['a', 1]
  ]
},
{
  id: 'beta',
  data: [
    ['a', 1],
    ['b', 1]
  ]
},
{
  id: 'alpha',
  data: [
    ['c', 3]
  ]
}]
```

you can do this traditionally with couple of for loops. but is there a easier way to reduce the for loop cycles and get this created. the caveat is, this must be strict JS I do not know how many users/teams/exps there might be. there may be 50 different users/1000 different experiments . So i can't hardcode any exp names/users/ etc.

Comment: don't stuff the ids in as values. use them as keys. `data['alpha']` is far easier to deal with than having to scan your parent array every time to figure out which index `id:alpha` is in.

Comment: @MarcB the reason i event want to create this nested object is becasue this is the format the third party chart library i use, expects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This proposal uses a single loop with a temporary object for the references to the result array's arrays.

```js
var array = [{ icon: 'm-warning', color: '#FDC204', name: 'exp1', team: 'c', user: 'alpha' }, { icon: 'm-puzzle', color: '#86AF45', name: 'exp2', team: 'c', user: 'alpha' }, { icon: 'm-refresh', color: '#77A746', name: 'exp3', team: 'c', user: 'alpha' }, { icon: 'm-puzzle', color: '#86AF45', name: 'exp3', team: 'a', user: 'beta' }, { icon: 'm-clock', color: '#4677A7', name: 'exp4', team: 'b', user: 'beta' }, { icon: 'm-warning', color: '#FDC204', name: 'exp5', team: 'a', user: 'gamma' }],
    grouped = function (array) {
        var o = {}, r = [];
        array.forEach(function (a) {
            if (!(a.user in o)) {
                o[a.user] = { _: { id: a.user, data: [] } };
                r.push(o[a.user]._);
            }
            if (!(a.team in o[a.user])) {
                o[a.user][a.team] = [a.team, 0];
                o[a.user]._.data.push(o[a.user][a.team]);
            }
            o[a.user][a.team][1]++;
        });
        return r;
    }(array);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(grouped, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce?v=control), which I feel is a bit easier to read and reason about.

```
let result = array.reduce((accumulated, value) => {
  // find existing user
  let user = accumulated.find(item => item.id === value.user)
  if (user) {
    // find existing team
    let team = user.data.find(item => item[0] === value.team)
    if (team) {
      // existing team found, increase count
      team[1]++
    } else {
      // existing team not found, add team
      user.data.push([ value.team, 1 ])
    }
  } else {
    // existing user not found, add user
    accumulated.push({
      id: value.user,
      data: [
        [ value.team, 1 ]
      ]
    })
  }
  return accumulated
}, [])  // start with empty array
```

[Here is a jsbin to try it out in your browser](http://jsbin.com/qogeyeb/1/edit?js,output).